# CSS float problems, works in IE, doesn't work in Chrome/FF.. I'm probably doing something wrong

Tags: html, css

I'm not terribly well-versed in CSS.. and don't know all of the major quirks yet.  Maybe someone can help me.  I've set up an image showing my code, a diagram of my DIVs, and examples of how it looks in IE versus Chrome/FF

[image: Diagram]

Can someone direct me to the proper way to go about this?

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/BuuuW/2/

It works fine in IE, but in Chrome and FF, one of the images is escaping its container, and the "content block" as I call it is going underneath the image it's supposed to be next to.  Each of the components has a css class despite my diagram saying there's no css.. currently there's just some basic styling for those (padding, text-indent, etc).

Thank you

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS. A demo on http://jsfiddle.net would be great

Comment: The image escaping its container shouldbe solved with a "clearfix": at the bottom of the `cbContent` div, put a div like this: `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`

Comment: @Blender Done!  http://jsfiddle.net/BuuuW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to the container will avoid the left part from continuing underneath the image on right:

```
.cb {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That'll create a new block formatting context and I won't explain that to you because others have done it better than I could :) http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

EDIT: didn't see that person.jpg was out of its parent on left: see other answer for the clearfix method :)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the part where the divs were going under the tree image.

Answer (score 1):

use the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) hack for `.cbContent` (include clearfix css and add class `.clearfix`) to have the box expand to fit the image on the left.

Edit:
Also, make sure you arent giving the same div a fixed width (i.e. 500px) AND padding. This might make different browsers behave differently due to how they interpret the box model. For more info on this, and great solution for this, read Paul Irish's blog post here:
http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick for the image escaping its container. It's still a little different at the bottom of person.jpg (a little more of a gap in FF/Chrome than in IE), but it's much better.

Comment: added an additional suggestion. Let me know if it helps